# Is there any way to disable share via link check box for all users other than admin in Nextcloud?

Tags: fileserver, nextcloud

In my Nextcloud server as "Allow users to share via link" option is enabled [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZejk.jpg), all users are able to share files via link[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NscA.jpg). I want to know is there any way to enable this "share link" checkbox only for admin, not for any other users? If yes, please let me know the procedure to do so. I have disabled "Allow users to share via link" option from settings, but it is getting applied for all users including admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you initially share the folder, or one of its parents, with the user (so the user doesn't own it), you should be able to control this with the **Allow resharing** setting.

Since is was shared already, it cannot be reshared.

[image: settings page - sharing - allow resharing]